# Java EE 7 FirstCup Tutorial - NetBeans - Compilation Error javax.ejb does not exist

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, netbeans, java-ee-7

I've followed http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/firstcup/doc/firstcup.pdf religiously - and am hitting a problem on 3.2.1.1. I'm selecting "Build" to build the project using Maven but I get the issue..

`firstcup/ejb/DukesBirthdayBean.java:[16,17] package javax.ejb does not exist`

as well as other related `package does not exist` errors.

This is the first time I've used Netbeans (and Maven for that matter) - so am guessing it is something straightforward that I haven't configured correctly. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for the basic question, but... Are you running it on a server?

Comment: No - just `Build`ing it using Netbeans / Maven

Comment: Have you configured Glassfish as described in chapter 1.2.3 "Configuring your Environment"?

Comment: The parent project has a dependency on javaee-api, and should download and install the JAR during step 3.2.1.1. In NetBeans, if you expand Dependencies under firstcup, is javaee-api-7.0.jar expandable? If not, there might have been an error installing the dependency. If so, try right-clicking firstcup and selecting Build with Dependencies.

Comment: @SubOptimal - yes, I have configured it exactly as described
@IanEvans - it's expandable, but when I right click and click 'Build with Dependencies', the same issue happens - i.e. `Compiling 3 source files to C:\glassfish4\docs\firstcup\example\firstcup-war\target\classes
-------------------------------------------------------------
COMPILATION ERROR : 
-------------------------------------------------------------
firstcup/ejb/DukesBirthdayBean.java:[16,17] package javax.ejb does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out something must have gone wrong with the dependency download of `javaee-api-7.0` - I could only see the META-INF directories underneath the jar itself. After manually downloading and installing the artefact, I was able to build successfully.

Huzzah!